# FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage is not invoked when my app is on background in flutter , its happening only in Ios devices

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios

I Am making an app which has push notification Property app is working when we hit notification on the foreground , but when app is on background my _backgroundHandler() method is not invoking, its happening only In IOS App Only

Answer (score 8):

also struggle this issue.

set payload as below. **mutable-content** make sense.

```
apns: {
    payload: {
        aps: {
            'mutable-content': 1, 
            'content-available': 1
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9381#issuecomment-1229167020

set "mutable-content:1" in payloads, iOS passes the notification to our notification service app extension.

For more information APNs payload, see the following links:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification

Comment: 'content-available': 1 did the trick for me

Answer (score 4):

Enable background fetch, background processing and remote notification in Xcode
[image: preview]

**Edit**

Add mutable key to payload

{
"to": "dWdhfjfjdbzbmjJ5....",
"content_available": true,
"mutable_content": true,

"data":
{
"message": "some msg",
"mediaUrl": "image url here"
},

"notification":
{
"body": "notification msg",
"sound": "default"
}
}

**EDIT**

```
var payload = {
    notification: {
      title: `msg title here`,
      body: `msg body here`
      }`,
    },
    // Set Android priority to "high"
    android: {
      priority: "high",
    },
    // Add APNS (Apple) config
    apns: {
      payload: {
        aps: {
          contentAvailable: true,
        },
      },
      headers: {
        //"apns-push-type": "background", // This line prevents background notification
        "apns-priority": "10",
      },
    },
    token: "dnqTQVso60GfnnuOjHv8_e:APA91bElr-K3xkQMdYHX8VMrasdfasdfkjhasidfgjn"
 };
```

Comment: Already did it, but same problem exists , I am sucking on it for 5 days I did  not find any solution of that

Comment: Also did you add permission to allow sound alert and badge?

Comment: yes i also allowed

Comment: All other push notifications are working?

Comment: yes all working in forground also

Comment: in android, all  state notifications are working , means foreground,background,and also kill state

Comment: sory to say but already added this in my payload but same result no message received in background handler

Comment: Try setting priority too ib apns

Comment: from app developer??

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Comment: "apns-priority":"5" did it like this but same result

Comment: i have an update in my ios mobile is this the issue ??

Comment: No an update available cannot be an issue. Should be some settings that's missing. Are you getting notification when the app is in foreground

Comment: yes i getting the notification when app is forground

Comment: And if i used content_available true it's showing 2 notifications first firebase server then it comes to my modified notification (means if I used  content_available true notification is coming in the background but first notification shows silently then my original notification come with image

Comment: Added a payload.. Please try that one

Comment: already tried to added the paylod and check same result coming 2 notification

Comment: first silently (Like when we send through direct firebase messaging server ) and second one is my modified notfication

Comment: Same problem with small body , notification also coming twice

Comment: Same issue here, all of a sudden it is not working. When I then opens the app the notifications arrives via local notifications package

Answer (score 2):

Adding this in my payload solved my issue:

```html
apns: {
    payload: {
        aps: {
            'mutable-content': 1, 
            'content-available': 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have face this issue too.

@goza's answer should been accepted.

This is my sending json.

```
{
   "message":{
      "token":"fcm token",
      "notification":{
         "title":"NotifyTitle",
         "body":"NotifyBody"
      },
      "data":{
         "title":"DataTitle",
         "body":"DataBody"
      },
      "apns":{
          "payload":{
             "aps":{
                "content-available":1
             }
          }
       }
   }
}
```